# Showing that $a_n \in \ell^{\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $a_n \subset \mathbb C$ is a sequence
>
> Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx_n \lt \infty$ $\forall x_n \in \ell^1$   then $a_n \in \ell^{\infty}$

What did I do :

$x_n \in \ell^1 \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n| \lt \infty $

Since $\mathbb C$ is a Banach space $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n \lt \infty $ and from Leibnitz rule $x_n \to 0$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx_n \lt \infty \Rightarrow$ $a_nx_n \to 0$ i.e. $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0$$ |a_nx_n| \lt \varepsilon $

$|a_n||x_n|=|a_nx_n| \lt \varepsilon \Rightarrow$ $|a_n| \lt \varepsilon /|x_n| $ and $|x_n|$ is a finite number thus terms of $a_n$ are bounded. So $a_n \in \ell^{\infty}$

I’m not sure about my writtens. It seems wrong to me. Could someone fix me please? Thanks a lot

Comment: If $x_n=0$ for all $n$ then you can have $\sum a_n x_n <+ \infty$ without $a_n \in l^\infty$. Do you mean:
$$\forall x_n \in l^1, \sum_n |a_n x_n| <+ \infty ?$$

Comment: You need to learn to read and write much more carefullly!  What you say you're trying to prove is obviously false. The exercise actually reads like this: Show that if $\sum |a_nx_n|<\infty$ for every $x\in \ell^1$ then $a\in\ell^\infty$.

Comment: @Delta-u I think $\forall x_n$ It’s written in my notes like this. There can be some mistakes because the notes are written by one of our professor’s students

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich@DavidC.Ullrich I’ve written what I see in my exercise list. As I said, they are written by a student and there are some mistakes in exercises and theorems. I’ve tried what I understand. Exercise can be mistyped or may be I have misunderstood. Sincerely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: try contraposition. Suppose $(a_n)_n\notin \ell^\infty$, and show that there is a sequence $n_k$ such that $\lvert a_{n_k}\rvert\geq k^2$. Using that, find a sequece $(b_n)_n\in \ell^1$ such that $\sum a_nb_n=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have just realized my mistake. My professor usually prefers direct proof :) kind regards

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but  at a glance, I would say that any direct proof would be actually this proof masquerading as a proof by contradiction masquerading as a direct proof.

Comment: I have asked this to my professor’s assistant she gave a proof but we have realized that it is wrong too. I don’t understand how can I show it unfortunately. What is wrong in my writtens?

Comment: @esrabasar: You did not use the hypothesis that $(x_n)_n$ is in $\ell^1$ anywhere. More importantly, you cannot conclude that terms of $(a_n)_n$ are bounded just because $\lvert a_n\rvert<\varepsilon \lvert x_n\rvert^{-1}$, precisely *because* $x_n\to 0$ (because this is basically the same as that $\lvert x_n\rvert^{-1}\to infty$). If it was *bounded away* from $0$, that would be a different story.

Comment: I have used $x_n \in \ell^1$ space in convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ but I think bounding is not true as you said. How can I bound $a_n$ or how can I show $sup_{n \in \mathbb N}|a_n| \lt \infty$ ?

Comment: @esrabasar: That's what I'm saying: you never really use that assumption. I really think a proof by contraposition is the best idea.

Comment: I am in you are absolutely right. Thanks a lot for spending time..